# HTML Safety with unique weblinks

Tags: html, paypal, hyperlink

I have a question to ask, because I'm no expert with HTML.

So, say if someone purchases something from me (or similar), they get a Transaction ID on PayPal. If I add that to my HTML project (after purchase, manually) and have a www.website.com/downloads/ captcha-required "login" where they enter their Transaction ID and the valid captcha of course, which then redirects them to www.website.com/customers/(Transaction ID)/ is this safe or not? Can people have spambots that test random text after the /customers/ until they get it? Sorry if this sounds dumb, I just don't want to do it if it isn't safe. Because people can just inspect element and see what it redirects to.

Thanks in advance for answers, sorry again if this sounds dumb.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not safe even if there's no chance of someone guessing the Transaction ID as people can still share the download link.

Comment: It's a download, so they could share it anyways. They can download it from another website already, where they actually purchase it.

Comment: I've figured a way to do it.